# Basic Flask: Adding Helpful Functions

Tags: python, flask

I've written a python script that works in terminal and am porting it to the web using Flask.  I've gone through parts of a tutorial (specifically: `http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world`)

I'm struggling a bit with where to put all the functions I use in my Python script.  The author () uses this code for a basic view:

```
def index():
    user = {'nickname': 'Miguel'}  # fake user
    posts = [  # fake array of posts
        { 
            'author': {'nickname': 'John'}, 
            'body': 'Beautiful day in Portland!' 
        },
        { 
            'author': {'nickname': 'Susan'}, 
            'body': 'The Avengers movie was so cool!' 
        }
    ]
    return render_template("index.html",
                           title='Home',
                           user=user,
                           posts=posts)
```

The problem is I don't have one function to call.  I have 15 or so and it looks like Flask only lets me call one function per view.  So I'm not really sure where to put all the helper functions that my "main" function will call.

Take the author's example code.  If I had a function `getPosts()` that returns an array of post objects, where would I put this?

Even if I'm allowed to put it under the route's main function (which I don't think is allowed anyway), it seems like poor organization to do that.

Edit:

Here's my views.py file:

```
  1 from flask import Flask
  2 app = Flask(__name__)
  3 from flask import render_template
  4 from app import app
  5 from app import helpfulFunctions
  6
  7 def testFunction():
  8     return 5;
  9
 10 @app.route('/')
 11 @app.route('/index')
 12 def index():
 13     #allPlayers = processGender(mainURL, menTeams)
 14     myNum = testFunction()
 15     return render_template('index.html', title = 'Home', user = user)
```

Answer (score 7):

You're not restricted to one function per view -- you can have as many as you want.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

def f():
    ...
def g():
    ...
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    <here you can use f and g>
    ...
```

Functions don't need to correspond to views -- only the `@app.route(...)` decorator makes it do that.

If you have a large number of other functions, it couldn't hurt to put them in another file. Then you can `import` the file and use them as above.

Comment: OK, so I put them in a separate file within my app folder (called it "helpfulFunctions.py.")  I have "from app import helpfulFunctions" at the top of my "views.py" file.  Then, within index, I have a function called "processGender(mainURL, genderTeam)"  mainURL is defined in helpfulFunctions.py and I pass in a dictionary for genderTeam.  Even so, I get "NameError: global name 'processGender' is not defined"...Any idea?  Thanks again!

Comment: I get similar errors when I define a basic function (as you do in the above answer).  When I save its resulting value into a variable within index(), I get a "global name 'user' is not defined" error instead...

Comment: I put my helpers in a class, import and instantiate the class and use it within the main flask script. Update your code with helpfulFunctions.py and your main flask script to see what the problem may be.

Comment: @bclayman what is your file structure? That is, what `.py` files do you have, what are their names, and what imports what?

Comment: @EliRose I have squashScraper as my main folder, within that I have folders app, flask, my_p3_env, tmp and file run.py.  Within app folder I have folders __pycache__, static, and templates and files helpfulFunctions.py and views.py.  Within folder flask, I have folders bin, include, and lib and file pyvenv.cfg.  In views.py, I have [see updated question]

Comment: @GG_Python Where should I put this class?  I'm assuming I would import it in my run.py file, yeah?  So if I had a helpfulFunctions class in my app folder, I'd do something like "import helpfulFunctions from app" at the top of my run.py file?

Comment: same folder as your flask server script should work fine just to get you started; personally i like less clutter in the main directory, and (using python3) something like from shared.models import class_name works for a file 'models.py' in the 'shared' folder under the main app folder (where your flask script is).