# Basic Flask: Using Helper Function w/in View

Tags: python, flask

I'm following Miguel Grinberg's Flask tutorial here:

```
http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates
```

I'm trying to add a helper function and, based on the response here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677420/basic-flask-adding-helpful-functions
```

should be able to define a helper function within my views file and make use of it.  For example, my `app/views.py` is currently:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def hey():
    return 'hey everyone!'
def index():
    user = {'nickname': 'Ben', 'saying': hey()}
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user)
```

My `app/templates/index.html` file is currently:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ title }} - microblog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> {{ user.saying }}, {{ user.nickname }}!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, when I run the local server, it renders as `"hey everyone!"` and that's it.  My `{{ user.nickname }}` doesn't seem to get picked up.

I took out the `{{ user.saying }}` part and re-started the local server.  It still says `"hey everyone!"` so clearly it's not updating based on the content I put in.  Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks,
bclayman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ title }} - microblog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> {{ user["saying"]}}, {{ user["nickname"]}}!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Oh do this:

```
def hey():   # <-- this function was being called not index()
    return 'hey everyone!'

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index(): # <-- this function will now be called b/c it is directly under routes
    user = {'nickname': 'Ben', 'saying': hey()}
    return render_template('layout.html', title='Home', user=user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that, I changed run.py originally but didn't mention in post. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

It's because the function index() never gets routed to. Remove the hey() function.

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def hey():   # <-- the decorators (@app.route) only applies to this function
    return 'hey everyone!'
def index(): # <-- this function never gets called, it has no decorators
    user = {'nickname': 'Ben', 'saying': hey()}
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user)
```

Decorators apply to the following function. So try just moving the decorators above the function they should route to, like this:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

def hey():   
    return 'hey everyone!'

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index(): 
    user = {'nickname': 'Ben', 'saying': hey()}
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user)
```

Comment: If that's the case, then how does the index page even know about the result of hey()?  More importantly, how would you recommend I go about getting both routes access to both functions?

Comment: See the edit. But now the other poster updated it too. Basically you just have to keep in mind that the decorators affect only the following function.